# Localizing Identity Server Razor pages and messages

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, blazor, duende-identity-server

I am developing a Blazor hosted WASM app with individual accounts, that by default uses Duende Identity Server. It works, but all the account management pages and messages are in English when I need them to be in French (I don't need a multilanguage version).

I found that to translate them, I can add the scaffolded Razor pages to the server project.
Now, I can translate the texts in the generated pages, but that brings a few questions:

- Has anyone (Microsoft?) already done that quite standard localization work? Would it be available to use?
- Texts to be translated are located in different locations: inline in the HTML, in data annotations... it's not easy to not forget any of them.
- Some messages (i.e. "You are logged out") seem to be buried into the DLLs, so I didn't find how to translate them.

I couldn't find many resources on the subject on the Internet, so any hints would be much appreciated.